# Link to post author but exclude administrator (on single.php)

Tags: admin, author

How to exclude administrators from the code below? 
 So **if** the current post author has the role of administrator, nothing will show.

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></a>
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the wordpress function `user_can` that accepts as arguments the id of the user and a string representing a capability or a role name ('administrator' in your case ) and returns a boolean value.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can

Referred to your code you can try this

```
<?php 
  if( !user_can( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 'administrator' ) ): ?> 
    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></a>
<?php 
  endif; ?>
```